# hola, tengo un problema al conectarme a mi base de datos

Tags: c#, mysql-workbench, visual, studio

al hacer mi conexion me marca un error que el metodo de autenticacion ´caching_sha2_password' no es compatible con ninguno de los complementos disponibles

y no se como resolverlos cuando mi password esta tal cual en la base

Comment: Bienvenido a SOes, https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour revisa este enlace para que veas cómo funciona el sitio, ayúdanos a ayudarte, revisa también este par de enlaces: https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask + https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4433/822 Luego edita la pregunta y agrega todo aquello que sea lo mínimo necesario para que cualquier usuario pueda reproducir tu escenario, de este modo incrementas las chances de obtener respuesta(s). Saludos.

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.